# How to load / unload an assembly using the lastest .NET 5.0 from previous .NetCore 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-5

I'm in the process of upgrading my code to .Net 5.0 from .Net Framework 4.8.
One of the useful upgrades deals with the possibility of loading and unloading assemblies on the fly without restarting the application. So far I've managed to code the following function in c# for loading an assembly.

However information on google on how to do it systematically, for instance as a plugin mod, enabling management of assemblies loaded / unloaded during the execution of the application is scarce or even non existent!!! So any help is greatly appreciated .

```
 private static FormCustomized loadLayout(global::System.String layoutFilename, global::System.String layoutNameSpace)
{
    FormCustomized mainForm = default;
    Type typeMainLayout = default;
    FileInfo layoutFile;
    layoutFile = new FileInfo(layoutFilename);
    layoutFile.Refresh();
    if (!layoutFile.Exists)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Layout file not found. You need to reinstall the program");
        return default;
    }

    try
    {
        Assembly assemblyRaw = Assembly.LoadFrom(layoutFilename);
        AssemblyLoadContext context = AssemblyLoadContext.Default;
        Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(layoutFilename);

        Type typeMainLayoutIni = assembly.GetType(layoutNameSpace + ".initializeLayoutClass");
        Object iniClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeMainLayoutIni, true);
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeMainLayoutIni.GetMethod("AssembliesToLoadAtStart");
        enVars.assemblies = (Dictionary<string, Environment.environmentAssembliesClass>)methodInfo.Invoke(iniClass, default);
        typeMainLayout = assembly.GetType(layoutNameSpace + ".mainAppLayoutForm");
        mainForm = Activator.CreateInstance(typeMainLayout, enVars) as FormCustomized;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return default;
    }
    return default;
}
```

Comment: in the time between i've found this article: https://github.com/natemcmaster/DotNetCorePlugins
that briefly explains how to code a pluigin system

Comment: and also this article: https://codetherapist.com/blog/netcore3-plugin-system/

Comment: Do either of those links answer your question?

Comment: @MiguelSilva the real name of .NET 5 is .NET **Core** 5, despite MS marketing terms. The docs and articles you need are .NET Core articles. The articles you link to all end up using AssemblyLoadContext, which has an [Unload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.unload?view=netcore-3.1) method. Have you tried using it? At least one of those articles uses `Unload` already

Comment: Both the article and the Github project support unloading

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, .NET 5 is an evolution of .NET Core. No, it is not named .NET Core 5. It's not just marketing, Microsoft have discontinued .NET Framework and declared the official name of the latest .NET as .NET 5.

Comment: @Corey [Not according to the .NET team](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/). `.NET 5 = .NET Core vNext`. You missed the point of the comment, and the last two years of confusion as people try to use their .NET Framework libraries in .NET 5 projects. People actually need to be told that .NET 5 is .NET Core 5, not .NET Framework 5, so they can't just change a version number to make their old apps work. .NET Core was rebranded to alleviate corporate fears against large migrations. There was a lot of confusion and outcry after Build 2019, especially on Twitter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, it was called vNext before they settled on the release name. And yes, it's confusing, and dumb, but it is what it is. That's the way things often are in Microsoft-land. If you go looking at the product descriptions, documentation and almost every official publication from microsoft you'll find .NET 5, not .NET Core 5. The closest you get is ASP.NET Core Runtime 5, which is a different product.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please refer to the launch announcement: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/

Comment: @Corey I know, because I've been answering .NET Core questions for 5 years. I've actually read those announcements 2 years ago. Since Build 2019 I had to explain to a *lot* of people that .NET 5 is Core, not Framework.  I know all fo that and more. I could tell you that even Microsoft MVPs (non-devs) thought that somehow the runtimes would be "Unified", because that's what the marketing message was. The best way to explain this to anyone is that `.NET 5 is actually .NET Core 5`.